# Error: failed to run custom build command for `ffmpeg-sys-next v6.0.1`

Tags: rust, ffmpeg

I am trying to make a program that converts a MP4 into a gif and vice versa by decoding its packets and encoding them into a MP4 (or gif), I am using ffmpeg-next package (which uses ffmpeg rust behind it) to do this, my operating system is Linux 22.04 Ubuntu LTS (ARM64). When i try to build the program using `cargo build` i am met with a very long error message.

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `ffmpeg-sys-next v6.0.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/parallels/Downloads/file-conversion-rs/target/debug/build/ffmpeg-sys-next-1aa9b27d2be5c242/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBAVUTIL_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SYSROOT
  cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=avutil
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBAVFORMAT_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SYSROOT
  cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=avformat
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBAVFILTER_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=SYSROOT
  cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  cargo:rustc-link-lib=avfilter
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBAVDEVICE_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: `PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS="1" PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS="1" "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "libavdevice"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  error: could not find system library 'libavdevice' required by the 'ffmpeg-sys-next' crate

  --- stderr
  Package libavdevice was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libavdevice.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libavdevice' found
  ', /home/parallels/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ffmpeg-sys-next-6.0.1/build.rs:733:22
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I am aware of the problem, it cannot find the libavdevice in the PKG_CONFIG.

I have tried installing the libavdevice package using `sudo apt install libavdevice` but Ubuntu cannot find it, i also tried installing the ffmpeg package directly, i had also searched the same error message, someone else had the same error [issue](https://github.com/zmwangx/rust-ffmpeg/issues/138) but after running the solution provided by someone it still does not build/work.

Answer (score 1):

Cargo is looking for packages and you (most likely) do not have them installed.

Install the following development libraries that FFmpeg uses, and this should work:

```bash
sudo apt install libavcodec-devlibavutil-dev libavformat-dev libavfilter-dev libavdevice-dev
```

To see what each library uses, run `sudo apt show <PACKAGE_NAME>` and read the description.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt install libadevice-dev`. Otherwise, try adding stuff like `-2.0`, `-3.16` etc to the end.

Edit: If you get any other errors like this, try running `sudo apt install lib[missing library]-dev`